# Is it possible to recover HTML form data from Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 (MS IE11)?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, html, internet-explorer-11, forms

I want to know if it's possible to recover HTML web form data from MS IE11.

The 4 scenarios that I'm interested in, are:

1. when you've **closed** IE11's process (`iexplore.exe (*32)`), but have ***not* restarted** or **shutdown then booted** your PC;
2. when you've **closed** IE11's process and **have restarted** or **shutdown then booted** your PC;
3. when you've **closed** IE11's process and **have restarted** or **shutdown then booted your PC**, ***but*** Windows has updated itself (or Windows has automatically updated *only* IE11) upon restarting itself/starting;
4. when IE11's process is **still running**, i.e. you haven't killed it (but it *might* be lagging or frozen/unresponsive...) and you (obviously...) ***haven't*** **restarted** or **shutdown then booted** your PC.

To cut a long story short, a few days ago I accidentally had both IE11 (v11.0.9600.18124) and Mozilla Firefox (v40.0.3) opened, and I had the same e-shop webpage opened on both of them. I was logged into my account in that e-shop and the webpage in question had an HTML form (purpose: 'Send message' to seller) and was (I think) served as `https:\\`.

I had to be *away from the keyboard* (AFK) for a while, and when I went back to my PC, I accidentally started writing the message in IE11 rather than in Mozilla Firefox. I noticed that too late and by that time, IE11 had already frozen for some reason, so I had to kill its process.

Is it possible to somehow recover the text of that HTML web form, or is it hopeless? And, theoretically speaking, would it have been possible to recover it if the webpage was `http://` and not `https://` (though it's dead obvious that no self-respecting e-shop should ever use `http://` instead of the more secure `https://`)? My particular scenario is like the one in scenario number 2 above.

I have [Lazarus: Form Recovery (at addons.mozilla.org)](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery) (now abandoned, but it still works in my version of Firefox) installed in Firefox and that saves me in such cases, but this time, the problem is with IE11. So, please don't advise me to ditch IE11 completely, I keep IE11 installed just because I sometimes have to test websites under it...

So far, I've found some clues for possible text form data recovery only for the **4th** scenario mentioned above, see http://benpiper.com/2011/11/how-to-recover-a-lost-form-in-internet-explorer-or-firefox-without-any-add-ons-or-pre-installed-utilities/ (basically, it's about downloading and installing [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and dumping the RAM of the `iexplore.exe` process and then analyzing it for string matches; backup of that same webpage on *archive.is*, in case that particular webpage goes down: https://archive.is/Q4SSB).

As a side note, if it's not possible to recover any of my data, I'd like to see some ways to avoid this problem in the future (for IE11), like some sort of *Lazarus*-like add-on for IE11, or some cross-browser bookmarklet with this functionality (= saving (backup & recovery of) HTML text web form data, e.g. at specified second intervals, etc.) that works in IE11, or even a `.bat` batch script, anything, except for keyloggers.

Comment: Was the message to your seller longer than this question you typed out on Superuser? (Time management question). I lose long messages sometimes due to bad internet connection, I would suggest retyping it, because recovering data off RAM would take 100 times longer.

Comment: @AaronGillion, The message was longer, I think. Even though your comment makes perfect sense, it doesn't answer the question that I asked, which is about whether or not HTML form data recovery from IE11 is possible, how to achieve it, and/or how to avoid it in the future via installing add-ons/etc. I wouldn't be asking this if retyping the lost message was trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to recover form data in *any* browser by using forensic RAM dump software.

- [Belkasoft RAM Capturer](https://belkasoft.com/ram-capturer)
- [Magnet Forensics](https://www.magnetforensics.com/computer-forensics/acquiring-memory-with-magnet-ram-capture/)

Quoted from Magnet Forensics:

> Since the memory collected by the utility is stored in a raw data
>   format, it can be analyzed by most memory analysis and forensic tools
>   including IEF, Volatility, and Mandiant Redline.

To answer your scenarios:

1. Recoverable
2. Probably, as long as computer hasn't been unplugged or turned off more than 10 minutes
3. Probably, as long as computer hasn't been unplugged or turned off more than 10 minutes
4. Absolutely recoverable

10 minute rule for RAM recovery is best explained by a user on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/99911)

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case (scenario number 2) I had the PC turned off for WAY more than 10 minutes... But your answer is very good.

Related questions:
1. Why is there such a 'no more than 10 minutes after unplugging/powering off/restarting' limit, i.e. what causes such a limit?
2. Will it work for non-ACII (i.e. Unicode) text in the lost forms?
3. And to finish this matter, how do I decide which `iexplore.exe` process I should dump as RAM (since there are many `iexplore.exe` for each opened tab) or is RAM dumping done en-masse, i.e. the whole RAM gets dumped?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole entire RAM gets dumped. That's why forensic companies provide additional software for one to decode a dump like that. Yes, RAM dumping will recover non-ASCII text. 10 minute rule pulled [from here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/99911)